# I can't stop finding one exact type of weapon?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

I've only been killing common enemies in Vorago Solitude like Eternals and Lost Legion enemies, however I've been only getting *one* kind of drop. White, fire, laser guns. Literally every single gun ever since the first one has been one regardless of manufacturer or prefix.

Any reason for this happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Do not adjust your television screen**. The Lost Legion Eternals in Vorago Solitude will drop common lasers  every time when they receive enough damage to ascend. Your game is not bugged, this is just what the Eternals drop. - [Source](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Lost_Legion_Eternal)

Comment: Thanks, I guess it just seemed more peculiar how it happened to be fire everytime.

Comment: I'm *pretty* sure they drop the weapon they're *using* (or at least, that's the idea), and I think they always use fire lasers. I'm not certain about that part though.